# Mern Stack with Auth0, How to add new fields to the user Schema like roles, Likes,

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, auth0

I have installed @auth0/auth0-react in my react app and used mongodb database in auth0 everything is fine here, but Since auth0 offers a login/Signup UI and when saving the user it has its own columns, I want to add new/other columns to the user, but I cant seem to find anything on google on where or how to do that, if anyone knows how to add other fields or has an article link that would be amazing. Thank you